# Cannot create container with more than 127 parents

Tags: docker

When execute

```
docker-compose up -d
```

I have the following error:

> cannot create container with more than 127 parents

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Helped it:

```
docker rmi $(docker images --filter dangling=true)
```

from https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/12624